# Send longitude latitude fronm geolocatio class to edittext in other class

Tags: android, geolocation

I tied to send longitude latitude from Geolocation class to loginActivity class but nothing shown on EditText in loginActivity 
Here is what I've done. 
In Geolocation Activity:

```
public static String lon;
public static String lat;
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, location.toString());

    lon = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
    lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("longitude", lon);
    intent.putExtra("latitude", lat);
    startActivity(intent);

    // etLatitude.setText(lat);
    // etLongitude.setText(lon);

}
```

and LoginActivity:

```
public static String lon;
public static String lat;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    TextView tvLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLongitude);
    TextView tvLatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLatitude);

    Intent in = getIntent();

    lon = in.getExtras().getString("longitude");
    tvLongitude.setText(lon);
    lat = in.getExtras().getString("latitude");
    tvLatitude.setText(lat);
 }
```

In activity_login.xml

```
<TextView
    android:hint="Longitude : "
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvLongitude"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvRegesterHere"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp" />
<TextView
    android:hint="Latitude: "
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvLatitude"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvLongitude"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I still get:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

use `in.getStringExtra("longitude");` instead of `in.getExtras().getString("longitude");`